# NodeJS to Client : large data sending performance

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, sockets

How can I send large data from NodeJS to Client? 
I tried this two:
1. Socket.io request
2. Ajax GET request
But both way are slow.
I am using mongoDB. Data size would be 1,000,000+ objects(1-2GB) but even 10,000 data sending, It is so slow.
How can I make it more faster? (Data reading time from MongoDB to NodeJS is no problem. )

**This is Socket.io code**

=> NodeJS

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.on('getData', function() {
            var items = TestModel.find();
            items.find({},function(err,obj){
                    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    socket.emit('responseData', obj[i]);
                    }
                    socket.emit('complete',"Item length : ");
            });
    });
});});
```

If I use socket.emit('responseData', obj), I ll get a overflow err

=> index.HTML

```
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
           <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
          <title></title>
       </head>
      <body>
    Socket.io Test
    </body>
      <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.emit('getData');
            var i=0;
            //socket.emit('getName');
        socket.on('responseData', function(data) {
          i++;
        });
    socket.on('complete',function(data){
    alert(data+i);
    });
      };
      </script>
    </html>
```

**This is Ajax GET code**

=> NodeJS

```
    app.get('/load',function(req,res){
            var items = TestModel.find();
            console.log("Model loaded");
            items.find({},function(err, obj){
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
                    console.log("Sent Models"); 
            });
    });
```

=> Ajax

```
  $(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get('/load', {}, function(data){
                    ...
            });
    });});
```

Comment: What is the large data used for? Does the client absolutely need all 2GB at once?

Comment: Yes. It is genome data. Really huge.

Comment: What exactly is slow? Is it network IO or a thing like `JSON.stringify(obj)`? What does a profiler say?

Answer (score 1):

#### compression

Check and/or enable compression, you could get up to 10x gain, depending on data and format. There's a tradeoff between compression quality and server cpu usage, in general, start with best compression algorithm browser (or client) supports.

If the client is under your control, you could even try `xz` or something more exotic :)

#### caching

Tag your responses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and add hooks for `If-None-Match: ...` request header field.

#### streaming

Depends on what the client is using the data for, is it saved? processed? displayed? In many cases client can start performing actions on part of data. If that part is at the start of response, streaming it makes a lot of sense

#### parallelize

Clients could use `Range: ...` request header field to download segments of data. In which case single client could issue multiple requests against segments of given dataset simultaneously. This typically helps if client's network is crappy (e.g. another continent).

#### preview

Perhaps client can process or "show" a simplified representation of data first. If there's a human user behind the client, they may wish to quickly check your data before making a decision to download it. Pretty common for images and design documents where a thumbnail or preview is generated server-side.